# Linux tar archive without parent structure

Tags: linux, tar

I'm trying to modify a certain tar.gz archive I have.
When I go to create the tar, it retains the parent directory structure, as a tarball should. However, is there a way to simply create a tar archive with just the files I specifiy, rather than the entire directory tree?

Comment: Would you accept a way to remove directories on extraction instead of creation? As @yarek answered, finding and piping the files shows that tar doesn't support this.

Comment: Well, some variants of *tar* do - see below.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling recursion in *tar*.

POSIX *[pax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html)*(1) has **-d** option which enables cpio-like interface while allowing to create *.tar* files.  Example from Wikipedia:

`find . -depth -print | pax -wd > archive.tar`

GNU *tar*(1) has an analogous option, **[--no-recursion](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/Choosing.html#SEC115)**. Example from there:

`find dir tests | tar -cf archive -T - --no-recursion`

P.S. I usually fall back to *cpio*(1) in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little dirty, but yes:

```
michael@choad:~$ tar cf - -C ~/scratch packing_slip_411.pdf -C ~/bin/df_linux/ README.linux | tar tvf -
-rw-r--r-- michael/users 37686 2012-03-30 15:09 packing_slip_411.pdf
-rwx------ michael/users  1364 2012-03-30 07:27 README.linux
```

Answer (score -1):

Specifying the full path of a file will preserve the tree:

```
tar cf newarchive.tar /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```

To omit the file structure, cd to the directory and create the archive:

```
(cd /path/to && tar cf /tmp/newarchive.tar file1 file2)
```